# Ruby on Rails - can not install SystemTimer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-1.9

I am using windows and I just ran the command:

```
C:\Sites\cmply>gem install SystemTimer -v '1.2.3'
```

and I got this error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing SystemTimer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating system_timer_native-i386-mingw32.def
compiling system_timer_native.c
In file included from system_timer_native.c:8:0:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
system_timer_native.c: In function 'install_first_timer_and_save_original_configuration':
```

any idea why? Prior to this I got another suspicious error:

```
Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3/ext/system_timer/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing SystemTimer (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install SystemTimer -v '1.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and prior to that I got another error that seemed to indicate that my Ruby version is somehow out of sync:

```
C:\Sites\cmply>bundle update rake
Updating git://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.2.3)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.1.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activesupport (= 3.1.3) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

So is it all rooted in me having an incompatible ruby version? How should this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Ruby has its default `Time` class. why do you need another gem for it?

Comment: Could you provide your Ruby version? The output of `ruby -v` command.

Comment: @uDaY `SystemTimer` is not equivalent with the `Time` class, it's a totally different piece of cake.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván, Yeah just read about the gem. Good to know thanks!

Comment: @KARASZIIstván ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the output it says you're building for Ruby 1.9.3 with the include files of 1.9.1.

It looks like your Ruby installation is somehow broken. I would try to reinstall the Ruby 1.9.3 and check that the include files exist in `c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.3/` and not in `c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/`.

Answer (score 19):

You can't install system_timer gem with ruby 1.9, but it's not a bug, it's a feature. Here is the [full explanation](http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer).

> "system_timer is only relevant if you are running Ruby 1.8. You do not
>   need it if you are running Ruby 1.9"

If you're switching from Ruby 1.8 to 1.9, simply remove the system_time gem and update code dealing with timeouts.